# Restoring a Facebook 3 SDK session

Tags: android, facebook

I am building an Android app with Facebook login and i am stuck at persisting a session to internal memory. Here's how i am instancing it:

```
private static Session openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean allowLoginUI, StatusCallback callback, List<String> permissions) {
    OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(activity).setPermissions(permissions).setCallback(callback);
    Session session = getSession(activity);
    if (SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED.equals(session.getState()) || allowLoginUI) {
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        session.openForRead(openRequest);
        return session;
    }
    return null;
}

private static Session getSession(Activity activity) {
    return new Builder(activity).setTokenCachingStrategy(new SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy(activity)).build();
}
```

Problem is that this code that checks if a session could be restored never fires because isOpened() will return false at all times

```
if((facebookSession = getSession(this)) != null && facebookSession.isOpened()) {
        waitDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, getResources().getString(R.string.pleaseWait), getResources().getString(R.string.loadingData));
        onPostLogin();
        return;
    }
```

I tried to get around this with these two functions:

```
private void saveFacebookSession() {
Bundle facebookCache = new Bundle();
        Parcel parceledCache = Parcel.obtain();
        Session.saveSession(facebookSession, facebookCache);
        parceledCache.writeBundle(facebookCache);
        try {
            FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput(FACEBOOK_SESSION_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
            byte[] marshalledParcel = parceledCache.marshall();
            Editor prefsEditor = preferences.edit();
            prefsEditor.putInt(RESTORE_BYTE_COUNT, marshalledParcel.length);
            prefsEditor.commit();
            output.write(marshalledParcel);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Could not save the facebook session to storage");
        }
}



private boolean restoreFacebookSession() {
        try {
            FileInputStream input = openFileInput(FACEBOOK_SESSION_FILE);
            int arraySize = preferences.getInt(RESTORE_BYTE_COUNT, -1);
            if(arraySize == -1) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Could not read the facebook restore size");
                return false;
            }
            byte[] sessionData = new byte[arraySize];
            input.read(sessionData);
            Parcel readParcel = Parcel.obtain();
            readParcel.unmarshall(sessionData, 0, arraySize);
            Bundle sessionBundle = readParcel.readBundle();
            facebookSession = Session.restoreSession(getApplicationContext(), null, (StatusCallback)this, sessionBundle);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Could not restore the session");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This second approach does not work because an exception is thrown about a magic number when reading the bundle.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to persist the Session? The data used to create a session (access token, expire date, etc) are all saved using the Token Cache, so you should be able to just create a new Session object every time your app restarts, and it will auto load all the necessary data from the token cache.

Comment: That did not happen, i had to explicitly call Session.openActiveSessionFromCache in order to get the previous session back.

Comment: Yes, that's true if you want the session to be in the open state, but calling that method is silent (meaning no user interaction), so you can call it every time. Alternatively, you can use the UiLifecycleHelper, which does all that for you. The key takeaway is that you should not have to serialize the Session into user store yourself.

Comment: Yes, i learned my lesson after digging through the source for the Facebook login button. I wont use UiLifecycleHelper as i *just* need to retrieve some info from the profile and post an action. That class is a bit of an overkill.

Comment: but why does Session.openActiveSessionFromCache() always returns null?

Comment: I solved that problem eventually but i cant remember how, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, the problem is you are not calling Session.setActiveSession() after you create the Session the first time so I guess that you as I did on the onActivityResult method were doing something like this:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        com.facebook.Session fbSession = com.facebook.Session.getActiveSession();
        if (fbSession != null) {
            fbSession.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

so the callback was never read from the facebook sdk getActiveSession always returned null.